# uncompress string recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am trying to un compress the string using recursive technic.  I have a code that works for some and gives me an  error for some like this **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""**

for example, when i send in a string like 4a4b4c or 40A5B10c it works perfectly fine.  The error comes when use string are like "a9T3b5R6t3h2g4v5b4n"

here is my code

```
public static  void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(uncompress("a9T3b5R6t3h2g4v5b4n"));
}

public static String uncompress(String Text){
    return uncompress(Text, "", "");
}

public static String count(char ch, int n){
        if(n == 0){return "";}
        return "" + ch + count(ch, n-1);
    }

public static String uncompress(String Text, String count, String output){
    if(Text.equals("")){
        return output;
    }
    if(Character.isLetter(Text.charAt(0))){
        output += count(Text.charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(count));
        count = "";
    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(Text.charAt(0))){
        count += ("" + Text.charAt(0));
    }


    return uncompress(Text.substring(1), count, output);
}
```

Comment: What is `decompress`?

Comment: Where is the `decompress()` ? please show us the full relevant source code.

Comment: @Abhi wheres the decompress method ?  you mean uncompress(Text,"",""); ?

Comment: Also make sure to check your code, `NumberFormatException` is thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that string might contain non-numeric characters like `a` or `#` etc

Comment: @Abhi where do you initialize this variable `newString` ?

Comment: A few style notes: you shouldn't have a method and a variable with the same name (`count`).  Variables should start with a lower case letter (`Text`).  Also, all of this could be written with iterative (not recursive) code and it would be more efficient and more readable.

Comment: decompress should be uncompress and newString is output, that was my bad I copied it wrong.  sorry @Secondo

Comment: yes, @NealEhardt you are right it can be written as iterative and it is also much easier.  But i am required to do it recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just handle the NumberFormatException(NFE) then put an alternative solution if the first input is a string then just retain it. im not quite sure about my explanation im open for correction . just want to help. TIA.

```
public static  void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(uncompress("abasd4a4b4c"));
}

public static String uncompress(String text){
    return uncompress(text, "", "");
}

public static String count(char ch, int n){
        if(n == 0){return "";}
        return "" + ch + count(ch, n-1);
    }

public static String uncompress(String text, String count, String output){
    if(text.equals("")){
        return output;

    }else if(Character.isLetter(text.charAt(0))){
        try{
            output += count(text.charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(count));
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            output += text.charAt(0);
        }
        count = "";
    }else if(Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))){
        count += ("" + text.charAt(0));
    }
    return uncompress(text.substring(1), count, output);
}
```

## Output:

```
abasdaaaabbbbcccc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get exception java.lang.NumberFormatException because if the string starts with letter, the code gets to

```
if(Character.isLetter(Text.charAt(0))){
    newString += count(Text.charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(count));
    count = "";
}
```

block, and you try to parse `count` which value is `""` since the first uncompress is called with `return uncompress(Text, "", "");`.

In conclusion, that code could only handle compressed string that starts with digits. Maybe you can try validate the inputted compressed string first to avoid the exception.